# How to remove section from TinyMCE link plugin

Tags: tinymce

In my app I using tinymce plugin for adding some files from local machine - link plugin. And it works great, but, there is one section - `target`, that I want to hide from users.
[image]

Because I'm just using '`_blank`' as default and type '`none`' make some troubles. 
In documentation I can't find option for hide this section. So I try to hide this by css. Unfortunately id and classes are dynamic, so it was bad idea with css '`display:none`'.

It's possible to hide this section somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the target list altogether by placing this in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
target_list: false
```

That is documented here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/#target_list

> To disable the option dialog set `target_list` to `false`

Comment: I missed that, thanx for your help!